# Is it possible to disable Windows Hello trying to be my FIDO2 credential?

Tags: windows, security, authentication, fido2, webauthn

Sometimes when I try to register using FIDO2, windows asks me for my Windows Hello PIN so that it can authenticate me.

Windows Hello asking for a PIN:
[image: Windows Hello asking for a PIN]

AFAIK this is windows offering to be a "Platform Credential", as-in, the FIDO2 credential is locked to my TPM? Not sure, don't care, I never want to use that, I use a security key, which pops up after I press cancel.

Prompt whether I want to register using security key:
[image: Prompt whether I want to register using security key]

A pin prompt for my security key:
[image: A pin prompt for my security key]

Now, I kinda realize that removing my Windows Hello pin would solve this, but then again, I like the pin, for signing in to windows... Is there a way to *just* disable the platform authenticator feature and only prompting for my roaming authenticator?

I also think this is rather bad as a UX, since users might have their security key connected, thinking they are using that, but when their computer pops off, all their credentials are gone.

Comment: “as-in, the FIDO2 credential is locked to my TPM?” - No; Your TPM has absolutely nothing to do with your problem.